# Angular4 - How to stagger the animation of an observable array

Tags: angular, animation, ionic3

I am trying to do a staggered animation on an array of observables in Angular4, here is my code:

```
  animations: [
    trigger('fade', [
      transition(':enter', [style({opacity: 0}), animate('2s ease')])
    ]),
    trigger('stagger', [
      transition(':enter', [
        query(
          ':enter', 
          stagger(
            '0.5s', 
            [animateChild()]
          ),
          { optional: true }
        )
      ])
    ])
  ], 

export class TimetablePage {
  classes: Observable<ClassTime[]>;
```

And my template:

```
  <ion-list [@stagger]>
    <timetable-item 
    *ngFor="let class of classes | async | sort: 'time'" 
    [class]="class"
    [@fade]>
    </timetable-item>
  </ion-list>
```

The fade animation is running but the animation is not staggered.